# Change HTML class using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html class using two class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    $('.green').addClass('display-on');
  });
  $(".container").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.black').removeClass('display-on');
  });
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="black">
    <h1>hello
      <h1>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
    <h1>hello
      <h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

I need the `container` `background-color` black when the mouse hover to class `black` h1.

and `container` `background-color` green when the mouse hover to class `green` h1

The code above does not work.

Comment: You're missing a `"` in the second line of your js

Comment: One of your lines is missing a closing `"` after `".container`. You are also adding/removing the `display-on` class from different elements.

Comment: oho .. sorry friend. i am  typing mistake

Comment: Don't use both `hover` and `mouseleave`. [`hover` takes two functions; the first called when the mouse is over, the second when the mouse has left](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). if you give it one function, the same function is called for both events.

Comment: You are adding and removing the class "display-on" but there's no definition of that class in your CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you said you want, it should be as easy as adding a hover function to each `div` which changes the class of the parent `.container` to reflect the hovered `div`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".green").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').toggleClass("green");
  });
  $(".black").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').toggleClass("black");
  });
});
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="black">
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need javascript to do this. You can do it in a couple of lines of CSS on its own:

```
.black:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
.green:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Edit: Since this appears to be using jQuery and I got the question a little wrong, you can do this instead:

[jsfiddle.net/L4t2kqhp](https://jsfiddle.net/L4t2kqhp/3/)

```
<div class="container"> 

 <div class="black">
   <h1>hello<h1>
  </div>

  <div class="green">
   <h1>hello<h1>
  </div>

</div>

$(document).ready(function() {   
    $(".black").hover(function() {
        $('.container').css("background-color", "black");
    }, function(){
    $('.container').css("background-color", "white");
});
    $(".green").hover(function() {
        $('.container').css("background-color", "green");
    }, function(){
    $('.container').css("background-color", "white");
});
});
```

Comment: The OP wants the `<div class="container">`'s background color to change.

Comment: Include the code in the question, not in a link people must follow.

Answer (score 2):

you could use this as your css instead:

```
.black:hover{
   background-color: black;
      }

.green:hover{
       background-color: green;
      }
```

Comment: You've just repeated what the existing answer already said, which is not an answer to the question the OP is asking.